# Kerberos SSO - klist get - should it work for every domain user?

Tags: active-directory, single-sign-on, kerberos, klist

I'm integrating SSO(Kerberos) with Keycloak (...)

In the process of troubleshooting this:
When using the klist get command:

```
>klist get HTTP/registered-spn.fqdn.com

Current LogonId is 0:0x145d2d
Error calling API LsaCallAuthenticationPackage (GetTicket substatus): 0x80090342

klist failed with 0xc00002fd/-1073741059
```

**My question:**

Should "klist get" return a positve result for EVERY domain user that will use SSO?
Or will this only work for domain admin accounts?

The user account registered in/with the SPN should have all needed permissions. When testing "klist get" with a domain admin account, I get a result, with a regular user not. Question is if this is expected or do all domain users that will use SSO need any special permissions as well?
(So again; should "klist get work" for everyone, and is "klist get" the first command that should work before proceeding?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should "klist get" return a positve result for EVERY domain user that will use SSO? Or will this only work for domain admin accounts?

Yes, it should return a positive result for every user. Acquiring a ticket (as `klist get` does) is the core operation of Kerberos SSO – it is in no way privileged.

That being said, it only works if your login session has the credentials to acquire tickets at all – meaning, either you must be logged in as a *domain* user, not a local user, or you must have Kerberos credentials stored in Credential Manager if you're using a local account.

If you're logged in as a domain user:

1. Test with a SPN of some other service that is guaranteed to work. For example, as you're most likely using Active Directory, test with `ldap/<fqdn_of_dc>` or `host/<fqdn_of_your_own_pc>`.
2. Fire up Wireshark, capture `port 88`, and check whether a Kerberos TGS-REQ is happening at all and whether it's failing for some reason.